# Add Interceptor for AFNetworking/Alamfire ios

Tags: android, ios, swift

I am working on SDK project which requires Interceptor. Which means When ever the developer calls AFNetwroking , before it calls to server I want to change the url and params based on condition. I have done successfully in Android using Okhttp.

Without changing too many codes I want to handle in the SDK. Please help me for my problem.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the swift version for okhttp interceptor. Use below link:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftInterceptor

Comment: do we have same thing for objective C

Comment: This should work:
https://github.com/xplatsolutions/iOS-Network-Interceptor

Comment: I am looking for request adapter in AlamoFire. Can you please tell me how it can be done in AFnetworking similar like Request Adapter.   https://grokswift.com/custom-headers-alamofire4-swift3/